# Выборка данных из нескольких таблиц TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть несколько таблиц, содержащих в себе всю информацию о партии.
Таблица с атрибутами партии, таблица потребления и расхода, движения партии. Необходимо создать скрипт, который по номеру партии(внешнему или внутреннему) выводил результаты множества отдельных селектов с данными, которые относятся конкретно к этой партии. Сложность заключается в том, что номер партии внешний - это номер посылки, а внутренний - совершенно другой.

```
declare @np nvarchar (60) = 'Q1332-05'
select top * 50 from n_atrib where num_part = @np
select top * 50 from part_transfer where num_part = @np
select top * 50 from trans_shedule where num_part = @np
select top * 50 from part_inv where num_part = @np
```

При такой конструкции, если np задать номером посылки, то в таблицах, которые относятся уже к "внутренней" кухне скрипт ничего не найдет, т.к. там используется номер другого формата.

Comment: Так, это всё отлично... а вопрос-то какой? Если задача - распознать, какой номер дали, и в зависимости от этого выполнить тот или иной запрос на получение требуемого в других запросах номера - ну так шаблоны поди известны, регэксп в руки, и вперёд.

Comment: Вопрос в том, что необходимо, чтобы вся цепочка таблиц открывалась, при этом указывался номер только внешний или внутренний номер посылки. Если запустить скрипт из примера, он вернет 4 таблицы, 3 из которых будут пустые из-за того, что номер партии там уже изменился на внутренний.

Comment: Для ответа на вопрос необходимо знать как преобразовать "внешний" номер к "внутреннему". Так как в вопросе этой информации нет, то задача не разрешима

Comment: Внутренний номер генерируется автоматически и помещается в таблицу атрибутов партии n_atrib с определенным attr_id = 3. По итогу в таблице атрибутов создается запись, которая содержит номер посылки в колонке p_value и внутренний номер в колонке num_part.

Comment: Значит надо его получить из этой таблицы атрибутов в переменную и использовать в других запросах

Comment: @Mike спасибо. Присвоил переменной селект и его уже использовал в других запросах.